# Handle process returns 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read handle process game, but if I try to read process handle, it always returns 0, can somebody explain this to me?

```
import ctypes, psutil
import sys

#DLLs needed
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
#Process Permissions
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = (0x0400)
PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = (0x0008)
PROCESS_VM_READ = (0x0010)
PROCESS_VM_WRITE = (0x0020)

#Windows API's
OpenProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess
CloseHandle = kernel32.CloseHandle
GetLastError = kernel32.GetLastError
ReadProcessMemory = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
WriteProcessMemory = kernel32.WriteProcessMemory
class ReadWriteMemory:

    def OpenProcess(self, myProcess):
        dwDesiredAccess = (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                           PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |
                           PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE);
        bInheritHandle = False
        for Process in psutil.process_iter():
            dfr = str(Process.name)
            i = dfr.find("name=")
            z = dfr.find(".exe',")
            if z == -1:
                z = i+8
            if dfr[i+6:z+4] == myProcess:
                dwProcessId = Process.pid
                hProcess = OpenProcess(
                    dwDesiredAccess,
                    bInheritHandle,
                    dwProcessId
                    );

                return hProcess
            elif Process.name == None:
                hProcess = None
    def CloseHandle(self, hProcess):
        CloseHandle(hObject);

    def GetLastError(self):
        GetLastError();
        return GetLastError()

    def PointerOffset(self, lpBaseAddress):
        pass


rwm = ReadWriteMemory()
handleProcess = rwm.OpenProcess('Empire Earth.exe')

print("handleProcess", handleProcess)
```

Result:

```
handleProcess 0
```

Comment: What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Before I find value. Example handleprocess = 982, But this time it no longer works with me, help please

Answer (score 0):

From the [`OpenProcess` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess)

> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified process.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

It means something went wrong during process creation and you need `GetLastError` to give you more specifics.

Comment: the GetLastError Is this a function?

Comment: How do I use this function in the python?  Help me please please please

Comment: It should be in the Win32 API DLLs, same as `OpenProcess`.

Comment: I did not understand anything,

Comment: Give me the YouTube link.
This is explained by the python

Comment: You're not going to get anywhere cobbling together chunks of source code you find online and hoping they work. If you understand how your `OpenProcess` call works, then you should be able to use the exact same technique to call `GetLastError`. If you don't understand how that call works, then you shouldn't be using it until you do. Slow down, get some practice with the basics, and learn Python fundamentals before trying to drive on the metaphorical interstate calling Win32 DLLs.

Comment: Thank you .
I agree with you .
But how do I get the basics of DLL Win 32?
Where do I start learning?
Is there a channel explaining all this information?

Comment: I am sorry for all these mistakes.
because I'm Arabic .
I use google translate.
I love the world of programming.
I reached a decent level in the Python.
I have a goal that I want to reach.
I will not give up .
With your help, I will go to the solution.
My goal is to complete the online game Trainer

Comment: [Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/) is the canonical source of WinAPI documentation. It's written for use in C++, but all of the types are C types and hence should translate to Python's `ctypes` module in a straightforward way.

Comment: getlasterror = rwm.GetLastError()
print(getlasterror) => getlasterror = 5

Comment: what does it mean 5

Comment: [Access is denied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). It's a permissions issue.

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: Thank you I found the solution, the solution was simple